# I want to retrieve the image from parse! Storing the image in parse works! How can i get the image from parse in imageview?

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
public class Profile extends Activity {

ImageView personal_ImageView;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 100;
private String selectedImagePath;
private ParseObject totem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    personal_ImageView = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.personal_imageView);

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    String currentUserUsername = currentUser.getUsername();

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) personal_ImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(selectedImagePath, data);
    file.saveInBackground();
    final ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("imageProfile");
    gameScore.put("image", file);
    gameScore.put("user", currentUserUsername);
    gameScore.saveInBackground();

    personal_ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

            ParseFile file = gameScore.getParseFile("image");
            final ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.personal_imageView);
            imageView.setParseFile(file);
            imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null){
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            personal_ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                    // The image is loaded and displayed!
                    int oldHeight = imageView.getHeight();
                    int oldWidth = imageView.getWidth();
                    Log.v("LOG!!!!!!", "imageView height = " + oldHeight);      // DISPLAYS 90 px
                    Log.v("LOG!!!!!!", "imageView width = " + oldWidth);        // DISPLAYS 90 px
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me guys...   I can upload the image to parse but i am not be able to retrieve the image and put it into the parse imageview! What am i doing wrong in the code?

Comment: <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/personal_imageView"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_100" />  This is my xml were i want to put the image...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Also, please [edit] your question to include additional info; don't add it in comments, because unformatted code/xml/whatevs is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at this:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Cheers!

Code I used to retrieve image from parse using file URL.

```
 ParseFile file = message.getParseFile(Insert Key File Here);
 Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());
 Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri.toString()).into(imageView);
```

Then you can add a callback to Picasso if you want like so:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri.toString()).into(imageView, new    com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

            //Success
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

         //Error Occurred  

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Gomes, i know how it works with picasso! The problem is i dont know how to get the image i stored on parse in my imageview!  How can i retrieve the image from parse? If somebody has any link or code so please help guys...

Comment: I did an app in a course that I upload Images and retrieve them I can put here the code that I use to retrieve Images from Parse.

Comment: That would be very helpfull for me Gomez!

Comment: See if what I added on the answer suits your purpose.

Comment: Hi Gomez, first thanks for your example! But by me its not working, what do you do precise in the code?

Comment: Basicly once you upload the image to the Parse server you can then  get the url of the upload file and use picasso to display it in the imageView. Try to just get the url and then print it to the log or make a toast to see if you are getting the url of the image.

Comment: Hi Gomez, i am trying now for 2 days to get the url of the file but it will not work... do you have a code snippet to do that?

Comment: Hi Gomez, how do i get the url from image in parse? I found nothing helpfully on the Internet?!