# How to Retrieve image and text via parse for image view pager - Android

Tags: android, image, text, parse-platform, slider

i'm a student that is still learning and improving on my android skills.

Currently i am using a image view pager that i used from https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider .
and images are stored statically in the drawable folder.

What i want to do is to be able to retrieve Images from Parse and place it in the image slider view.

from what i read from this link "[I want to retrieve the image from parse! Storing the image in parse works! How can i get the image from parse in imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286924/i-want-to-retrieve-the-image-from-parse-storing-the-image-in-parse-works-how-c)" ,

i still dont quite understand how it works. Hopefully someone can help me. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener{
private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

    HashMap<String, Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    file_maps.put("TAPA-APAC SCC 2015", R.drawable.supply_chain_conf);
    file_maps.put("TSR", R.drawable.trunking_security);
    file_maps.put("FSR", R.drawable.facility_security_requirements);
    file_maps.put("TAPA Air Cargo", R.drawable.tapa_air_cargo);
    file_maps.put("Self Certification", R.drawable.self_certification);
    file_maps.put("Get Certified", R.drawable.get_certified);

    for (String name : file_maps.keySet()) {
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
        // initialize a SliderLayout
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

        //add your extra information
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra",name);

       mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
    mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Default);
    mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
    mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // To prevent a memory leak on rotation, make sure to call stopAutoCycle() on the slider before activity or fragment is destroyed
    mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

    Toast.makeText(this,slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);
    }


@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
```

}

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: @Ormoz  Hello, i have insert my codings in the above.  i have edited the coding to what i want to have.